# Google App Engine ndb dynamic indexes alternative

Tags: database, google-app-engine, indexing

**Background**

I'm creating an application that allows users to define their own datasets with custom properties (and property types).

A user could, while interacting with the application, define a dataset that has the following columns:

- Name:String
- Location: Geo
- Weight:float
- Notes:Text(not indexed)
- How many:int

etc...

While there will be restrictions on the total number of properties (say 10-20 or something), there are no restrictions on the property types.

Google's ndb datastore allows this to happen and will auto-generate simple indexes for searches involving combinations of equality operators and no sorts, or only sorts.

**Ideal**

- Multiple sorts
- Equality and sorts
- Combinations of inequalities

I'm trying to determine if I should use NDB at all, or switch to something else (SQL seems extremely expensive, comparatively, which is one of the reasons I'm hesitant).

For the multiple sorts, I could write server-side code that queries for the first, then sorts in memory by the second, third, etc. I could also query for the data and do the sorting on the client side.

For the combinations of inequalities, I could do the same (more or less).

These solutions are obviously not performant, and won't scale if there are a large number of items that match the first query.

BaaS providers like Kinvey (which runs on GAE unless I'm quite mistaken) use schemaless databases and allow you to both create them on the fly and make compound, complicated queries over the data.

**Sanity Check:**

Trying to force NDB into what I want seems like a bad idea, unless there's something I'm overlooking (possible) that would make this more doable. My solutions would work, but wouldn't scale well (though I'm not sure how far. Would they work for 10k objects? 100k? 1M?).

**Options I've investigated:**

- Kinvey, which charges by user and by data stored (since they just changed their pricing model), and ends up costing quite a bit.
- Stackmob is also nice, but cloud code is crazy expensive ($200/month), and hosting and such all just costs more. Tasks cost more. The price looks very high.

**Question:**

I've done a fair bit of investigating, but there are just *so many options*. Assuming that my sanity check is correct (if it's not, and doing in-memory operations is sort-of-scalable, then fantastic!), are there other options out there that are inexpensive (BaaS providers get quite expensive once the applications scale), fast, and easily scalable that would solve my problem? Being able to run custom code in the cloud easily (and cheaply) and have API calls and bandwidth cost next to nothing is one of the reasons I've been investigating GAE (full hosting provider, any code I want in the cloud, etc).